# Symfony2 form in modal is not handled

Tags: jquery, forms, twitter-bootstrap, symfony

I'm rendering a form from a form class into a modal based, then performing different actions depending on which button was pressed. The purpose of the form is to edit an entity.

When I display the form in a modal, it won't process it regardless of which button I press, however when I render the form in a new tab, all actions are performed correctly.

Strangely enough, even though in my code right now the redirect that pushes the user back to the full resource list is disabled, the page still refreshes when I click a modal button.

**Solution:**

I needed to manually add the form action to the form in the modal so that it calls the correct controller action for processing. There wasn't much discussion in order to reach this solution, so for the convenience of others, here we go:

```
{{ form_start(form, {'action': path('sfi_teacher_manage_resource', { 'id': resource.id, 'action': user_action })}) }}
```

My form class:

```
<?php
namespace SFI\MainBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class ManageResourceType extends AbstractType
{
  public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
  {
    $builder
      ->add('name', 'text', array(
        'required' => true,
        'attr' => array(
          'class' => 'form-control',
          'placeholder' => 'Resource name',
        ),
      ))
      ->add('type', 'choice', array(
        'required' => true,
        'empty_value' => 'Choose a type',
        'choices' => array('w' => 'Website', 'v' => 'Video', 'a' => 'Audio'),
        'attr' => array(
          'class' => 'form-control',
        ),
      ))
      ->add('link', 'text', array(
        'required' => true,
        'attr' => array(
          'class' => 'form-control',
          'placeholder' => 'Add a link',
        ),
      ))
      ->add('description', 'textarea', array(
        'required' => true,
        'attr' => array(
          'class' => 'textarea',
          'style' => 'width: 100%; height: 200px; font-size: 14px; line-height: 18px; border: 1px solid #dddddd; padding: 10px;',
          'placeholder' => 'Write a description...',
        ),
      ))
      ->add('save', 'submit', array(
        'attr' => array(
          'class' => 'btn btn-success',
        ),
      ))
      ->add('remove', 'submit', array(
        'attr' => array(
          'class' => 'btn btn-danger',
        ),
      ));

  }

  public function getName()
  {
    return 'modifyResource';
  }

  public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
  {
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
      'data_class' => 'SFI\MainBundle\Entity\Resource',
    ));
  }
}
```

My route for this action:

```
sfi_teacher_manage_resource:
    path:     /teacher/resource/manage/{action}/{id}
    defaults: { _controller: SFIMainBundle:Teacher:manageResource }
```

My controller action:

```
public function manageResourceAction($id, $action, Request $manage_request)
{
  $logger = $this->get('logger');

  $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

  $managedResource = $em->getRepository('SFIMainBundle:Resource')->find($id);
  $logger->info('Started the manage action');

  $manageResourceForm = $this->createForm(new ManageResourceType(), $managedResource);
  $logger->info('Loaded managedResource into FormType.');

  $manageResourceForm->handleRequest($manage_request);

  if ($manageResourceForm->isValid())
  {

    $logger->info('Form was valid.');

    if ($manageResourceForm->get('save')->isClicked()) {
      $logger->info('Save was clicked, editing resource.');
      $managedResource->setStatus("1");
      $logger->info('Status set to approved.');
      $em->persist($managedResource);
      $logger->info('Resource was persisted.');
    } elseif ($manageResourceForm->get('remove')->isClicked()) {
      $logger->info('Remove / Decline was clicked');
      $em->remove($managedResource);
      $logger->info('Resource removed.');
    }

    $em->flush();
    $logger->info('Flushing...');
    $logger->info("Redirecting to teacher's resources...");
    //return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('sfi_teacher_resources'));
  }

  return $this->render('SFIMainBundle:Teacher:manageResource.html.twig', array(
    'user_action' => $action,
    'form' => $manageResourceForm->createView(),
  ));
}
```

As you can see I had to bake in some console logging to figure out at which point the action stops working.

If I open the form as a new tab, all is fine, but not in the modal. It's been suggested to me that some JavaScript may be getting in the way of the submit buttons working correctly, but I have no idea where start debugging.

If you require more information please let me know!

EDIT 1: As requested, I am including how I define and create the modal.

On my resources.html.twig, where the list of resources is being loaded, I have a couple of links like this, for each entity:

```
{% if r.status == "0" %}
  <a href="{{ path('sfi_teacher_manage_resource', { 'id': r.id, 'action': 'review' }) }}" data-target="#manageResource" data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-info bold" id="review"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-check-circle"></i>Review</a>
{% elseif r.status == "1" %}
  <a href="{{ path('sfi_teacher_manage_resource', { 'id': r.id, 'action': 'edit' }) }}" data-target="#manageResource" data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-info" id="edit"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-edit"></i>Edit</a>
{% endif %}
```

The modal itself is pre-built in the same template, as Symfony requires this to be so when working with Bootstrap modals (I have used modals un SF before, and this is the only way I can think of getting them to work when loading data or forms into them):

```
<div class="modal fade" id="manageResource" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="Manage resource" aria-hidden="true">
 <div class="modal-dialog">
  <div class="modal-content">
   Loading...
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

The **modal-content** gets replaced with the contents of **manageResources.html.twig**, once the object is retrieved and loaded into the form:

```
{{ form_start(form) }}
<div class="modal-header">
  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
  <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Manage resource</h4>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
  {{ form_errors(form) }}
  <div class="form-group">
    {{ form_errors(form.name) }}
    {{ form_widget(form.name) }}
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    {{ form_errors(form.type) }}
    {{ form_widget(form.type) }}
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    {{ form_errors(form.link) }}
    {{ form_widget(form.link) }}
  </div>
    {{ form_errors(form.description) }}
    {{ form_widget(form.description) }}
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
  <div class="pull-left">
    {% if user_action == "review" %}
    {{ form_widget(form.save, { 'label': 'Approve' }) }}
  {{ form_widget(form.remove, { 'label': 'Decline' }) }}
    {% elseif user_action == "edit" %}
    {{ form_widget(form.save, { 'label': 'Save' }) }}
    {{ form_widget(form.remove, { 'label': 'Remove' }) }}
    {% endif %}
  </div>
  <div class="pull-right">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
  </div>
</div>
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

That about covers all the code that is involved in this operation.

Comment: What does `manageResource.html.twig` look like ? How do you build the modal ?

Comment: I will add this information to my initial question as it requires some code and I can't possibly fit it all in here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for posting your templates code, I'll take a closer look at it asap.
One idea : I would try setting explicitly the form's action in **manageResources.html.twig**
Try something like this (adapt with correct parameters) :

```
{{ form_start(form, {'action': path('sfi_teacher_manage_resource', { 'id': resource.id, 'action': user_action })}) }}
```

Comment: There seems to be a punctuation error there, like the first colon but nothing I try works. Also, do I actually need my variables to be passed back with the action? Is this because I'm expecting them in my controller?

Comment: Thanks paulgv, this is the syntax I ended up using and it works correctly. There was an encapsulation problem with your proposal but this worked: {{ form_start(form, {'action': path('sfi_teacher_manage_resource', { 'id': resource.id, 'action': user_action })}) }}. Thank you again!

Comment: Hey sorry about that ! Thanks for the edit, I'm already starting to forget how Twig works :D
Glad to know you solved the problem :)

Comment: I wouldn't have if you didn't point in the right direction. Thanks again! P.S. Watch out for s keg of beer falling near you haha this drove me nuts for several days.